# Get ComboBox displayed text in WPF

Tags: wpf, combobox, tooltip

I am trying to add a tooltip to a combo box's style (so that it applies to all combos across the application). I want to display the item currently displayed on the combo box.

In some cases, combo boxes are bound to complex entities (classes) and a property of that class is set as the display member, for example:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SomeDataSource}"
          DisplayMemberPath="PropertyName" />
```

Also in some cases, I'm binding the combo boxes with a list of string, and therefore, I am not setting the DisplayMemberPath.

Is there a way to get the currently displayed value for the combo box?

**Edit**: The solution proposed below works just fine, although I'm facing issues with combo boxes with an ItemTemplate set (those item templates have a TextBlock with multi binding within them).

The combo boxes with ItemTemplate don't have a DisplayMemberPath, so the 'Text' property of the combo box is returning the SelectedValue.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
    <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Text}"/>
</Style>
```

You may want to add a converter to display a useful tool tip when the Text property is empty.

In order for the style to apply to all combo-boxes, put it in  in App.xaml.

Comment: Thanks a lot! WorksForMe (TM).

Comment: With the latest testing, seems like it shows the SelectedValue and not the text displayed. I instead want the displayed text to be shown as the tooltip as well.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  If you're binding to a list of strings then the selected value is the displayed text.

Comment: For list of strings, it is fine. What doesn't work is when I bind with complex class entities.

For instance, say I'm binding it with a UserCountry class, then the DisplayMemberPath may be CountryName, but SelectedValuePath is CountryCode. I wish to display the text that comes from the DisplayMember in the tooltip.

Comment: It works for me when setting DisplayMemberPath and using complex entities.  What do you mean 'it shows the SelectedValue'?

Comment: Alright, after doing some testing, looks like it fails when I am using a ItemTemplate. In such cases, no DisplayMemberPath is set.

Comment: You'll probably need to change the binding in the style to Path=SelectedValue.MyProperty where MyProperty is a property on your complex entity.

Comment: I know, but I want to have a centralized solution.